# Сортировка запроса по String атрибуту с помощью JPQL

Tags: spring-jpa

В таблице существует атрибут "Квартира". Он представляет из себя номер квартиры 1,2, 3 и тд. Однако бывает такое, что номер квартиры 1А или 2Б. Поэтому тип данных String (varchar). Для вывода данных необходимо как то отсортировать по номеру квартиры чтобы выводилось скажем 1,1А, 2, 2Б. Реально ли это сделать на уровне JPQL запроса?

Comment: Делай два уровня сортировки. Первый - по значению, конвертированному в число, второй по полному. Типа `ORDER BY CAST(num AS INTEGER), num`. Как это будет выглядеть в JPQL, чтобы без ошибок - разбирайся сам...

Comment: Дело в том, что при касте строки с буквой в integer вылетает ошибка даже при обычном запросе к БД: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "213А"

Comment: Потому я и сказал - разбирайся как. То, что операция возможна - сто процентов. Выделяй подстроку, пользуй регэксп или ещё что...

Comment: В нативном запросе смог реализовать это только с помощью: order by

CASE WHEN APPARTMENT~E'^\\d+$' THEN CAST (APPARTMENT AS INTEGER) ELSE CAST(substring(APPARTMENT,1,char_length(APPARTMENT)-1) AS INTEGER) END. Однако JPQL такой запрос не принимает..

Comment: Думаю, если у вас данные в строке, то он по умолчанию должен сортировать так как вам надо.